# How to set checkbox checked in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to check my checkbox at edit time in Zend form.
I have code for checkbox

```
    $master = new Application_Model_DbTable_MasterTables();
    $functionalList = $master->buildSelectListbyTable('mst_functional_areas', 'id', 'functional_area', "enable = '1'");

    $area = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('functional_area');
    $area->addMultiOptions($functionalList)->setLabel('Functional area of Specialization / Interest *:')->setAttrib('class', 'required');

    $this->addElement($area);
```

Now i have array at edit time

```
Array
(
    [id] => 9
    [user_id] => 15
    [work_experience] => 12
    [functional_area] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )
    [industrial_sector] => a
    [add_date] => 2014-01-27 12:06:03
)
```

functional_area is the array.So i want to check functional_array's value checked with the checkboxes.

Comment: you can use `'checked'=>true`

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = Array
(
    [id] => 9
    [user_id] => 15
    [work_experience] => 12
    [functional_area] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )
    [industrial_sector] => a
    [add_date] => 2014-01-27 12:06:03
);

$area->setValue($data["functional_area"]);
```

You can set values like above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setValue()` like this `$area->setValue($functional_area);`

Comment: I did some testing and it has to work. You call `setValue()` on MultiCheckbox object passing array of selected items. This will select by default items passed in `addMultiOptions()`(in setValue you pass keys from array you pass to addMultiOptions). Eg. For `addMultiOptions(1=>'option1`, 2=>'option2', 3=>'option3;)` and `setValue(array(1,3))` you will get `option1` and `option3` selected. Be sure not to overwrite this by setting `setDefaults()` or `populate()` on form object.

Answer (score 0):

Always check source code e.g. – [Checkbox.php](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/Element/Checkbox.php#L194). You can try `setChecked(true)`.